# Does "Stop aping!" sound natural?

Tags: word-choice, american-english

A teenager is acting in a very silly and annoying way making faces and rapidly changing his postures. His father gets really annoyed by it and tells him "Stop aping!"

Does "Stop aping!" go okay here or it's a bit unnatural? If the latter is true, what would you say in that situation? (American English preferred)

Comment: That's brilliant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*To ape* means, generally, *to imitate*, and thus isn't appropriate in this context.

The father might tell his son to *stop monkeying around*, which really just means fooling around. *Horsing around* is another option.

Comment: Yup. "Stop aping *me*" is perfectly idiomatic, but doesn't mean what the OP wants it to mean.

Answer (score 1):

[As onomatomaniak says](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/54786/3231), it's not appropriate in the context as *aping* means imitating.

Other things the father might say:

- "Stop clowning around!"
- "Stop fooling around!"
- "Stop joshing around!"

Comment: Your third example is less suitable than the others, as *[josh](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/josh)* ("To tease someone in a kindly fashion; to make or exchange good-natured jokes") is verbal not physical.

Comment: Cut the tomfoolery son, or I'll take a switch to your backside!